# rename files in mac terminal containing ';'

Tags: replace, terminal

I am trying to rename files from a client that contain ';' as when i upload them to my sever the files upload with zero bites.

I am using the below script (i have echo so that i can see the function work before i apply)

```
file in */*; do echo mv "$file" "${file/;/|}"; done;
```

this does not rename the file

But if i do this

```
file in */*; do echo mv "$file" "${file/VOLVO/|}"; done;
```

it does replace "VOLVO" with "|"

how can i replace the ";" with "|"

Comment: I assume there's a `for` in there?  `for file in ...;do echo stuff; done`?  Also, you should use `*/*\;*` so you don't do a lot of redundant `mv same same`.  `foo=b\;r;  echo "${foo/;/|}"`  **works for me in bash4** (Ubuntu).  Maybe try quoting the `;`, in case OS X bash3 is different?  (Like Tim's answer says; was going to give the `\;` syntax when his answer appeared.)

Comment: Also, for mass-renames, there are tools like `mmv` or `prename` (sometimes just called `rename`, implemented in perl).  http://www.unix.com/man-page/linux/1/prename/.  That way you only have to start one process that makes lots of `rename` system calls, rather than forking a whole process for every rename.  For one-off interactive use in shell one-liners, the best choice depends on which makes it easier to express the transformation you want: a shell text substitution or a pattern in prename or mmv.

Comment: Thanks. It worked when i tried to comment out the ';' with a for file in */*; do echo mv "$file" "${file//;/|}"; done;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with some advice own the forum by commenting out the ';' with a '/'

as below
    for file in */*; do echo mv "$file" "${file//;/|}"; done;

Thanks to Tim and Peter for the fix